# Pandas - Handling NaNs in categorical data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I have a column in dataframe that has categorical data but some of the data is missing i.e. NaN. I want to carry out linear interpolation on this data to fill the missing values but am not sure how to go about it. I can't drop the NaNs to turn the data into a categorical type because I need to fill them. A simple example to demonstrate what am trying to do.

```
col1  col2
5     cloudy
3     windy
6     NaN
7     rainy
10    NaN
```

Say I want to convert  `col2` to categorical data but retain the NaNs and fill them using linear interpolation how do I go about it. Lets say after converting the column to categorical data it looks like this

```
col2
1
2
NaN
3
NaN
```

Then I can do linear interpolation and get something like this

```
col2
1
2
3
3
2
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

> Is there a way to convert the data back to its original form after
>   interpolation ie instead of 1,2 or 3 you have cloudy,windy and rainy
>   again?

**Solution:** I've intentionally added more rows to your original DF:

```
In [129]: df
Out[129]:
   col1    col2
0     5  cloudy
1     3   windy
2     6     NaN
3     7   rainy
4    10     NaN
5     5  cloudy
6    10     NaN
7     7   rainy

In [130]: df.dtypes
Out[130]:
col1       int64
col2    category
dtype: object

In [131]: df.col2 = (df.col2.cat.codes.replace(-1, np.nan)
     ...:              .interpolate().astype(int).astype('category')
     ...:              .cat.rename_categories(df.col2.cat.categories))
     ...:

In [132]: df
Out[132]:
   col1    col2
0     5  cloudy
1     3   windy
2     6   rainy
3     7   rainy
4    10  cloudy
5     5  cloudy
6    10  cloudy
7     7   rainy
```

**OLD "numerical" answer:**

IIUC you can do this:

```
In [66]: df
Out[66]:
   col1    col2
0     5  cloudy
1     3   windy
2     6     NaN
3     7   rainy
4    10     NaN
```

first let's factorize `col2`:

```
In [67]: df.col2 = pd.factorize(df.col2, na_sentinel=-2)[0] + 1

In [68]: df
Out[68]:
   col1  col2
0     5     1
1     3     2
2     6    -1
3     7     3
4    10    -1
```

now we can interpolate it (replacing `-1`'s with `NaN`'s):

```
In [69]: df.col2.replace(-1, np.nan).interpolate().astype(int)
Out[69]:
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
Name: col2, dtype: int32
```

the same approach, but converting interpolated series to `category` dtype:

```
In [70]: df.col2.replace(-1, np.nan).interpolate().astype(int).astype('category')
Out[70]:
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
Name: col2, dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Is there a way to convert the data back to its original form after interpolation ie instead of 1,2 or 3 you have `cloudy`,`windy` and `rainy` again?

Comment: @WasswaSamuel, i've updated my answer - please check

Comment: Its amazing how much one can learn by going through these answers. Todays take home factorize() and interpolate() :)

Answer (score 2):

I know your asking for linear interpolation but this is just another way if you want to do this easier.As converting categories to Numbers isn't such a good idea I suggest this one.

you can simply use the interpolation method in pandas library with method 'pad' like:

```
df.interpolate(method='pad')
```

you can also see other methods and example of using them in [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html). (link is the pandas documentation of interpolation)

Comment: Notice that, at the moment, there are a couple of bugs affecting `df.interpolate(method="pad")`, see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26796 and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29146